# Service to accept SQL queries and run in the background

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a service to accept large numbers of SQL queries and run them in the background with retires and logging?

I have multiple clients running large numbers of queries directly against a SQL Server database but because they’re only inserts it would be far more efficient to post the queries to some service which can run them offline in transactions freeing the clients from having to wait for the queries to finish and reducing the connections to the database.

Because the result isn’t needed by the application, I’d like to “fire and forget” the SQL statements knowing they’ll eventually complete, even if they need to retry due to timeouts or network issues.

Does such a service exist?

Comment: You may be looking for a message queue, which SQL Server supports.

Comment: That’ll do messages but I actually want to run queries. So I’m looking for something I can maybe http post statements to and know they’ll eventually get executed in my database.

Comment: You can write a simple windows service application to run in the background and process tasks given to it by some sort of queue (e.g. msmq or message broker software, or just picking the next item from a database table). The client application meanwhile would just add the necessary data to the queue and then return.

Comment: "Result isn't needed"? Think again - someone or something needs to know. When things start to fail and you (or more likely, someone else) must determine why and correct the problem, you will appreciate this. Keep in mind that to retry effectively means you must undo any partially successful results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does such a service exist?

There is not such a service out-of-the box.  As suggested by Gordon Linhoff, you can SEND the batches into a [Servcie Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-2017) Queue, or INSERT them into regular Table, and have a background process run them.

In the case of Service Broker, the setup, programming, and troubledhooting is a bit trickier, but you get the [Internal Activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms171583(v%3Dsql.105)) to trigger a stored procedure you write when messages appear on the queue.

With a regular table you would just write a SQL Agent job (or similar) that runs in a loop and looks for new rows in the target table, runs the batches it finds, and deletes (or marks) the batches as complete.  You don't get the low latency and automatic scale-out that Service Broker Activation provides, but it's much simpler to implement.